# $\frac{|1 - 2x|}{\sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 4}} \leq x$ what is $x$ sufficient for this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> $\frac{|1 - 2x|}{\sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 4}} \leq x$

|1 - 2x| and $\sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 4}$ positive, then $x \geq 0$

in order to get $\sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 4} > 0$ then, $x > -2$

for $x < \frac 12$ , |1 - 2x| is 1 - 2x.

for $x > \frac 12$ , |1 - 2x| is -1 + 2x.

for $x = \frac 12$, |1 - 2x| = 0.

for $0 \leq x < \frac 12$ we get

$\frac{1 - 2x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 4}} \leq x$

for $x > \frac 12$ we get

$\frac{-1 + 2x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 4}} \leq x$

for $x = \frac 12$ we get
$0 < \frac 12$

but what is the $x$ for this condition?

Comment: You say for $x<\frac{1}{2}$, $|1-2x|=-1+2x$, and for $x>\frac{1}{2}$, $|1-2x|=1-2x$. Shouldn't this be the other way around?

Comment: What are you assuming, and what are you trying to prove?  If $x=-1000$ the inequality in the title obviously fails.

Comment: Hint: It is $\frac{|1-2x|}{|2+x|}\le x$ or $|1-2x|\le x |2+x|$ which is clearly wrong for $x\le 0$ and for $x\geq 0$ it is true iff $$\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{x\geq \sqrt 5 -2}$$

Comment: for $x = 1$ we get 1 < 3, still true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would like to point out a small error in your question's description. You have mentioned that $\left(x^{2}+4x+4\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is positive for all x>-2. But if you observe care fully, then you will notice that the discriminant of $x^{2}+4x+4$ is 0, and therefore, it can never be negative.

This implies that whatever x you plug into this function, excluding x=0.5, the output will always be positive.

And needless to mention, $\left|1-2x\right|$ is defined such that it always gives positive outputs.

What this means is that we can rule out the negative portion of the line y=x, because it does not satisfy the required inequality, as $\frac{\left|1-2x\right|}{\left(x^{2}+4x+4\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ is positive at all values of x.

Now, we need to narrow down the set of values of x which satisfy this inequality further.

Simply solving for x such that $\frac{\left|1-2x\right|}{\left(x^{2}+4x+4\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ = x, we obtain x=0.236.

It can also be observed that the function $\frac{\left|1-2x\right|}{\left(x^{2}+4x+4\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ is decreasing from negative infinity to 0.5, and increasing from o.5 to positive infinity. This gives us a clue to further restrict our analysis to these domains separately.

Now, it can easily be determined that from x=0.236(point of intersection) to x=0.5, the values of $\frac{\left|1-2x\right|}{\left(x^{2}+4x+4\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ are less than those of x. And the rate of increase of $\frac{\left|1-2x\right|}{\left(x^{2}+4x+4\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ from 0.5 to positive infinite is much lesser than that of x(find both derivatives and compare their maximum values, so that you can arrive at this conclusion by yourself).

So from x=0.5 to positive infinity, $\frac{\left|1-2x\right|}{\left(x^{2}+4x+4\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ is still less than x at any input.

From this, we conclude that $\frac{\left|1-2x\right|}{\left(x^{2}+4x+4\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}} \leq x$ from x=0.236 to positive infinity.

$x\in \left [ 0.236, \right (\infty) )$ should be your answer.

Comment: How do we obtain x = 0,236?

Comment: equate both the expressions and solve for x. It's a simple quadratic equation

Comment: that's the main question for me, how to solve for that?

Comment: $(1-2x)^2 = x^2(x^2 + 4x + 4)$

Comment: sorry. i got it wrong.

Comment: noo we get $(1-2x)^2 = x^2(x^2 + 4x + 4)$ which to 4th power?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HH6xmO0nHbg

Comment: this should help

Comment: actually we have $x^4 + 4x^3 + 4x - 1$ but somehow i factorize it..

Comment: btw, why excluding x = 0,5?